# Controlling the input detection on a 1/4" jack

Tags: audio

So, I have a midi piano that outputs to it's speakers when there's no 1/4" jack in it's line out, and else only outputs to the line out. It's rather annoying having to constantly remove and replug the cable when I want to switch between these, so I'd like to build something to allow say an arduino to do it.

So I'd basically be rigging a 1/4" jack to be able to "pretend" its not plugged in, somehow.

I can't seem to find anything similar online, and after looking at the jack schematic, don't even know where to start.

Would anyone be able to make suggestions/point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The device is a Yamaha DGX-660

Comment: That would depend on the shape of the particular socket contacts. Are you opposed to opening the device and defeating the detection or tapping out the signal?

Comment: I would rather not, since it cost ~£700, but I wont completely outrule it

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: use a linear actuator driven by an Arduino to mechanically pull and insert the plug.

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/bf/8f/d4/bf8fd4d35ef0247bb311b17b489e7b78.jpg ha

Comment: That's not realistically practical - in part, because you'd need to manually attach to the instrument to "pull against" while pushing in the plug, or build some sort of fixed enclosure constraining it and your device.  And then you'd need to actually find an actuator that was strong enough, but not so strong as to cause damage.

Comment: It leaves the MIDI piano untouched, as wished by OP. Looks to me the wrong forum to discuss mechanics, but to reply: Lot's of electronics projects are neither practical, still they're fun. Why wouldn't mechanical/mechatronics solutions be fun? And damage protection: use e.g. a spring (like in the funny picture!)  or bending rod etc.

Answer (score 0):

The switching function is almost certainly done mechanically, by switch contacts in the output jack that are moved when you insert a plug.  If that is the case, there is nothing you can do externally to over-ride the internal switch.

Comment: If I were to open up the device, would  it just be a case of connecting a transistor/relay to said contacts?

Comment: A different jack with switches (https://www.cui.com/blog/understanding-audio-jack-switches-and-schematics)

Comment: A relay would be safer.  There's a good chance that it'll always output to line out, with the disconnect happening because you pulled the plug.  In that case you could just rewire the jack to always drive the speakers.  If you're nervous about it and have the money, an amp repairman could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Although the Amplifier changes levels when the headphone plug is detected to reduce the power level, this can be changed.  ( see page 58 of your [user manual](http://media.datatail.com/docs/manual/338788_en.pdf).)

Thus to bypass the DPDT internal jack switch to fake "not plugged in" the contacts must be closed externally with a DPDT slide switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN6ymp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>